# Diferença entre SELECT convencional e INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Modelo da estrutura das tabelas:

```
Tabela: Bancos
Cod
Nome

Tabela: OperacoesBanco
Cod
CodBanco
ValorOp
Historico
```

Bom tenho esses 2 modelos de `SELECT`:

Exemplo 1

```
SELECT
 b.Nome,
 o.ValorOp,
 o.Historico
FROM
Bancos b,
 OperacoesBanco o
WHERE
 b.Cod = o.CodBanco
```

Exemplo 2

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 Bancos
INNER JOIN
 OperacoesBanco
WHERE
 Bancos.Cod = OperacoesBanco.CodBanco
```

Bom esse dois modelos de `SELECT` funcionam e me retornam a mesma resposta. O que quero saber é se eles possui uma diferença de desempenho em um BD grande ou qual a melhor forma de utilizar eles.

Resumindo qual seria o melhor?

Comment: Não creio que exista alguma diferença de desempenho, até por que os otimizadores cuidarão desse aspecto. Eu prefiro a opção explicitando o INNER JOIN para facilitar a leitura por parte dos humanos (explícito vs implícito). De qualquer forma você pode eliminar sua dúvida avaliando o plano de consulta gerado pelo ANALYZE para ambos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso depende da engine do banco. Semanticamente falando, o `JOIN` é mais claro, mas do ponto de vista de performance precisa ver o plano de execução da query.

Montei essa tabela do seu exemplo e extrai o plano de execução de ambas as queries e **o resultado foi o mesmo**:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table Bancos (
  Cod int primary key,
  Nome varchar(50)
);

create table OperacoesBanco (
  Cod int primary key,
  CodBanco int references Bancos(Cod),
  ValorOp float,
  Historico varchar(100)
);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
    explain SELECT
     b.Nome,
     o.ValorOp,
     o.Historico
    FROM
    Bancos b,
     OperacoesBanco o
    WHERE
     b.Cod = o.CodBanco;

| id  | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra       |
| --- | ----------- | ----- | ---------- | ------ | ------------- | ------- | ------- | --------------- | ---- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | o     |            | ALL    |               |         |         |                 | 5    | 100      | Using where |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | b     |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.o.CodBanco | 1    | 100      |             |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
explain SELECT
 *
FROM
 Bancos
INNER JOIN
 OperacoesBanco
WHERE
 Bancos.Cod = OperacoesBanco.CodBanco;

    | id  | select_type | table          | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra       |
    | --- | ----------- | -------------- | ---------- | ------ | ------------- | ------- | ------- | ---------------------------- | ---- | -------- | ----------- |
    | 1   | SIMPLE      | OperacoesBanco |            | ALL    |               |         |         |                              | 5    | 100      | Using where |
    | 1   | SIMPLE      | Bancos         |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.OperacoesBanco.CodBanco | 1    | 100      |             |
```

Então, para esse modelo de tabela, o resultado é o mesmo do ponto de vista do plano e performance. Claro que ao adicionar outros critérios isso pode mudar de acordo como o motor do banco, mas analisando simplesmente a link das tabelas, para o `mysql`, a performance será a mesma.

Foi executado e exportado a partir do DB Fiddle: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rbLCS17pCvHo2PQQXCJRPn/1)